# Can a template template argument from different namespace be a friend?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I apologize if the title of this question is less than helpful; I don't know a succinct way to ask this question without giving the following example:

```
template <template <class> class Arg>
class C {
    typedef C<Arg> type;
    friend class Arg<type>;
  public:
    C() {
        a_.set(this);
    }
  private:
    int i_;
    Arg<type> a_;
};

template <class Type>
class Arg1 {
  public:
    void set(Type* t) {
        t_ = t;
        t_->i_ = 1;
    }
  private:
    Type* t_;
};

namespace NS {

    template <class Type>
    class Arg2 {
      public:
        void set(Type* t) {
            t_ = t;
            t_->i_ = 2;
        }
      private:
        Type* t_;
    };

}
```

As you can see, `Arg2` is a copy of `Arg1`. However, VS 2008 only allows `Arg1` to be used as a template argument:

```
int main() {
    C<Arg1> c1; // compiles ok
    C<NS::Arg2> c2; // error C2248

    return 0;
}
```

The error is `'C<Arg>::i_' : cannot access private member declared in class 'C<Arg>'`. Everything works fine if `i_` is made public, so this seems to be a friendship issue.

What is causing the friendship declaration to fail when the template template argument is in a different namespace?

Comment: I should add that the same code also fails to compile in both VS 2010 and VS 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace membership does not affect eligibility for friendship. This is a compiler bug.

`friend` and `namespace` are language features that interact, though, so it's not particularly surprising as bugs go. Perhaps it's actually friending a nonsense forward declaration in the enclosing namespace, `::Arg2<type>`.

Comment: Given the other (now deleted) comments indicating that clang and gcc compile my example without errors, I'm thinking this is the correct answer.